# How to turn down and up the quality of video in webrtc video call in Android

Tags: android, webrtc

I am currently working on video chat webrtc android application based on the native java webrtc library, its working fine, I need to adjust the quality of the video to be high when when the internet speed is high and low when the internet speed is low, I've done successfully the first part(getting callbacks when the internet speed changes) my question is how to change the quality of the webrtc video

Comment: Interest Question. For sure you can control video size in same time you control quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the callback of the internet-speed change call the following function:

```
videoCapturer.changeCaptureFormat(width, height, framePerSec);
```

to reduce the quality of the video reduce the 'width', 'height', and 'framePerSec'.

Note: the lower the values the lower the quality, the higher the values, the higher the quality, to set the best values, I recommend search on the topic "best video dimension" like in this link

```
https://support.brightcove.com/optimal-video-dimensions
```